# Enums - Expression of type 'X' has no member named 'Y'

Tags: apex, enum

Consider the following method:

```
public string WriteBoundary(
    EndingType endingType) {
    string boundary = '';

    if (endingType == EndingType.Cr) {// <- Error!
        boundary += '\n';
    } else if (endingType == EndingType.Normal) {
        boundary += '\r\n';
    }

    boundary += '--' + this.Boundary + '--';

    blob boundaryBlob = blob.valueOf(boundary);

    return EncodingUtil.base64Encode(boundaryBlob);
}
```

Where the `// <- Error` comment is, I get an error saying that `EndingType` does not have a member called `Cr`, yet it very clearly does:

```
private enum EndingType {
    Cr,
    CrLf,
    Normal
}
```

So, what am I doing wrong in this comparison?

Comment: change parameter name *endingType* to anything else, there might be conflict

Comment: @llyaLepesh you can put this as answer

Comment: I agree with @IlyaLepesh. In docs, there's an example of `public enum Season {WINTER, SPRING, SUMMER, FALL};` followed by `Season e = Season.WINTER;` Your code is analogous to changing that to read `Season season = Season.WINTER`.

Comment: That was it. @IlyaLepesh, please put this as an answer so I can give you credit. Two weeks of morning-evening programming makes you blind to the simplest things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that Salesforce can't differentiate your Enum name with parameter name, which are same.
Try to change parameter name to something else:

```
public string WriteBoundary(EndingType e) {

    if (e == EndingType.Cr) {
```